# Error in amsmath package preventing my latex document from compiling?

Tags: errors, amsmath

I am currently trying to compile a latex document but get the following error message.

```
Command \iiint already defined. ...{\iiint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{3}}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Most likely you have `\newcommand{\iiint}` somewhere... Impossible to say more without [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You may also consider accepting answers to your previous questions before shooting a new one...

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by switching the position of the lines `\usepackage{tikz, wasysym}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}`. Not sure why this worked, but glad that it did.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- you're correct.  (i hadn't checked.)  erroneous comment deleted.